# How to get Query output with distinct fields

Tags: mysql, sql, database, psql

```
  source   | destination | totalkms >
-----------+-------------+----------
 chennai   | bangalore   |      400
 bangalore | chennai     |      400
 mumbai    | delhi       |     1400
 delhi     | mumbai      |     1400
 delhi     | patna       |      800
```

expected output is

```
  source   | destination | totalkms 
  ---------+-------------+----------
 chennai   | bangalore   |      400
 mumbai    | delhi       |     1400
 delhi     | patna       |      800
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not exists` and `union all`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.source < t.destination
union all
select t.*
from t
where t.source > t.destination and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.source = t.destination and t2.destination = t.source and
                        t2.totalkms = t.totalkms
                 );
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try [least()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) and [greatest()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) methods with group by clause as below.

`select least(source, destination),greatest(source, destination),max(totalkms) from test_travel group by least(source, destination),greatest(source, destination);`